# May I use 'Good job, sir' to appreciate my boss' work?

Tags: american-english, british-english, register, greetings, dialect

Somewhat, I feel it down using this sentence to our seniors, especially our boss.

> Good job, sir

Or...for that sake..

> Well done, sir

I need natives' input for this. If I'm working for you/under you, and want to appreciate your efforts, may I say those sentences? Will you feel down/offended/ridiculous? Because I'm too small to speak this?

On the other hand, a CEO can certainly say this to another CEO. My basic question is `good job/well done` is okay when a person in low hierarchy refers to the higher authorities?

Comment: It totally depends on the relationship you have with your boss.

Comment: I see...this means on the very second day at my office...I cannot say... @δοῦλος

Comment: The time you have been on a particular job with a particular boss will certainly be part of what I meant. But it is also possible you knew or know the guy from some other context (church or bowling team), or worked for him before, or vice versa, so again: it depends on the relationship you have with your boss, and, as a second factor, the personality types involved.

Comment: For example, I share a very common relationship with my boss. Just 'hi, hello' etc. And I'm appreciating him for his task. I think it'll be **then** improper to greet it that way. What say? @δοῦλος

Comment: This question is not just about word choice but includes all kinds of cultural considerations. I have no idea how the norms and expectations of your culture compare to mine. So I couldn't hazard a guess of an answer. How else *might* you compliment your boss? But I think asking folks not familiar with the cultural norms you operate within is misguided.

Comment: By "feel it down" do you mean it seems to you like a **put-down** or **talking down to** your boss?

Comment: @BrianHitchcock I mean hesitating, not feeling that it's proper...

Answer (score 6):

In Britain, the expression *good job* when used by a superior to a junior is considered patronizing.  It is not used as a compliment.

I wouldn't use it at all except as a joke, if you knew the person you were speaking to would understand the joke.

A simple *well done*  or *nice one* is much more acceptable and can be used between people of any position.

In the USA, the phrase *good job* is used much more often and has no negative connotations that I know of.

Comment: Well, there is ["Brownie, you're doing a heck of a job"](http://content.usatoday.com/communities/theoval/post/2011/06/heck-of-a-job-brownie-calls-bush-inattentive-fratboy/1).